# As a shortening of "bourgeois", is "bougie" or "bourgie" correct?

Tags: orthography, formality, african-american-vernacular-english, clipping

*Bougie* or *bourgie* is used as a shortened, informal version of *bourgeois* used in African American Vernacular English. For example:

> The car he drives is indicative of his **[*bougie* | *bourgie*]** lifestyle.

A look at [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bourgie%2Cbougie&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbourgie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbougie%3B%2Cc0)

[image: ngram of bougie/bourgie]
reveals that [*bougie*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bougie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) is used much more often 
than [*bourgie*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bourgie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bourgie) has a definition only for *bourgie*,
listing *bougie* as a less common variant — which directly contradicts
the Google Ngrams results.

The only other useful info I can find the site [verysmartbrothas.com](http://verysmartbrothas.com/the-difference-between-bougie-boujee-and-bourgiebourgeois-explained/), which doesn't seem like a great source.

But which spelling is more correct?

Comment: I have not heard either of those.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. You should provide research to show that this an actual usage.

Comment: Do you mean research to show that either of this terms exist? They both show up in Google ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bourgie%2Cbougie&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbourgie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbougie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Jones When you add in bourgeois  to the ngram the other two become practically zero. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bougie%2Cbougie%2C+bourgeois&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBOUGIE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbougie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBOUGIE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbourgeois%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbourgeois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBourgeois%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ... and better to update the question with your additional info rather than just in comments.

Comment: I've edited the question to include my research. How can I request the hold be removed?

Comment: @Jones I'll reopen it, but you should understand that “more correct” isn't really something that makes sense to linguists. One can report on varying levels of acceptability based on interviews, or on varying levels of occurrence in various corpora (which, in a sense, you have yourself already done). The OED2 admits only *bougie* here, not the other spelling.

Comment: Thank you, the root of my question is not knowing which spelling to use. How do you think I should phrase the question?

Comment: @tchrist  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21989?redirectedFrom=bougie#eid) bougie; [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/258817?redirectedFrom=bourgie#eid) bourgie.  Resolving this is beyond my pay grade.

Comment: I have never ever heard bourgie with an r. The slang usage of bougie may does derive from bourgeois but the usage is very different. One term is marked as educated + and/or historical, and the other is contemporary slang. For purposes  of the OP's question), I'd go with bougie.

Comment: Interestingly, the song is called "Bad and Boujee"

Comment: @Lambie The r in 'bourgeois' is silent, so presumably so would be the r in bourgie. I guess it's really a question of whether today's speakers recognize the term as a contraction of bourgeois or as an independent word.

Comment: @Quantum7 The r is bourgeois is not silent. The r is dropped in the slang term: a bourgeois lifestyle, a bougie lifestyle. AmE speakers who say boo or bougeois, just do not know. It's like femme fatale, people say: FEM fatale, and it's fa, like the note, famme fatale.

Comment: @Lambie Interesting, I always heard /ˈbɔːʒ.wɑː/ (considered UK on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bourgeois) despite my AmE dialect), but [Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bourgeois?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) lists \ ˈbu̇rzh-ˌwä as an option too. I'm not sure what you mean by femme fatale, this is /fɛm fəˈtæl/ and definitely not /fɑ/ like the music note.

Comment: @Quantum7 These types of questions have to answered by people who have actually heard these things. Dictionaries in this case do not count in my opinion. In the short, newish form the r is never pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

From this ngram, both *bougie* and *bourgie* are so rare **in comparison to** *bourgeois*, that I'd suggest avoid using them and stick to the full word.

Even if they are not "wrong", they're far from idiomatic.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that _bougie_ and _bourgie_ are seen less than bourgeois. They are both fairly limited to ebonics, which (I would assume) is not very well represented in google's dataset. Aside from that, I asked this question because I was trying to write down what someone was saying.

Comment: @Jones Ebonics as in African American Vernacular English ? Maybe you should update question regarding that usage. BTW Until now I'd never heard of Ebonics!

Comment: I have never seen bourgie in my entire 60+ years. People say bougie for bourgeois all the time. Dunno about Afro-American dialectal usage, however. I prefer not to use the word Ebonics.

Comment: -1 This comparison isn't useful at all. "Bougie" is used in completely different domains than "bourgeois" and a raw count isn't informative.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai my point was *bougie* barely used anywhere as can be seen from the tiny raw count. Thus, no need to investigate in depth its domain/usage.

Comment: And my point is that the fact that ngrams only counts that many doesn't make it an uninteresting question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Urban Dictionary, Bougie is:

"Aspiring to be a higher class than one is. Derived from bourgeois - meaning middle/upper class, traditionally despised by communists."

Example in Urban Dictionary:

"When my friend Miya wears a blazer or Lucy gets a massage I call them bougie cause we're unemployed college students."

Comment: I saw the Urban Dictionary definitions for both, but that don't really answer my question.

Comment: Urban Dictionary also has boojee, boujee, bougee, bourgy, etc. with similar definitions.

Answer (score -1):

I would say bourgie is more accurate. But that's my opinion, mostly because of the 'r'. Bougie is used more as a slang than anything else, bourgie is only known to and consciously used by people aware of the fact that they're referring to the shortened form of the word bourgeoise. Half of the people who say bougie and actually think of it spelled as bougie are likely not to be aware that it was derived from the word bourgeoise.

Comment: Pardon me. *bourgeoisie.

Comment: I'm no linguist, but isn't the spelling determined primarily by how people spell it, as opposed to the etymology?